# Tools to measure the nonrandomness of database

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, random-variable

I was working on historical data looking for anomalous patterns that we would not expect to occur at random. I'd like to create a scheme to analyze data and markets to test for statistical significance and consistency over time.

**Question :** Are there some tools we could use to evaluate the nonrandomness of a database? What do we use usually to say that something is random or not (statistically)? Figure we work with change in some value over time.

Comment: I suspect you might not be happy with correct answers to your question about what "completely random" means, because they won't tell you much about how to analyze data, test for statistical significance, or evaluate consistency over time.  If you could frame a (much) more specific question you would likely get relevant answers.

Comment: To give you a sense of why your general question isn't likely to be productive, consider that one of the best tools for assessing randomness (or lack thereof) is just to compress the database as much as possible.  The ratio of the original length to the compressed length measures the "nonrandomness."  But so what?  Therein is the problem: "patterns" involve far more than mere "randomness" or the lack thereof.

Comment: Sandra - I think you want to google "anomaly detection". the things people would do is build a model eg data is normally distributed (with mean/standard deviation based on eg last weeks data) and then test if today's data is likely given this assumption.  [issue is building correct model - eg maybe you have hourly cycles etc, you have to fit that into your model].

Comment: This question is stated in the most general way - if you were to instead sharpen your focus to specific kinds of patterns or relationships, it would become much more concrete and answerable. For example, are the patterns you are interested in about the change in some value over time? That's the domain of timeseries analysis.

Comment: What do you mean by randomness? What exactly would you like to measure?

Comment: @Tim So far I don't have a formal definition of randomness. I work with some databases from the stock like the corn price, gas price, so on. I wish we could give me ideas on how I could go about it, give me some ideas.

Comment: It's important to state beforehand what kinds of patterns you're looking for, because anything can be made to seem anomalous after the fact.